# Display dropdown based on values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three dropdown boxes.
My first drop-down select box looks like this

```
<select name="peos" id="peos" class="peos form-control" >
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8+</option>
        </select>
```

And my second looks like this

```
<select name="peosone" id="peosone" class="peosone form-control" >
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8+</option>
        </select>
```

And third looks like this

```
<select name="peostwo" id="peostwo" class="peostwo form-control" >
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8+</option>
        </select>
```

If i select value **3** from my first drop-down , i should be able to select only three option from second and third drop-down (i.e) 1,2,3.

Where as rest of the option should be disabled or non-selectable.

And if i select value **2** from second drop-down ,the third drop-down should be able to select only **1**. ((i.e) 3-2) and vice versa.

Similarly, the same logic should be applied for all the way of possible option values selected on first drop-down box

Suggest me the best solution on javascript or Jquery for my query.

Comment: You can just disable options you don't want to be selected. There is [disabled](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp) attribute on `<option>` element. So add event listener on change of select elements, and then decide which options should be disabled.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort

Answer (score 0):

Listen for change events and do some logic like so:

```js
$("#peos").on("change", function() {
  var currValue = parseInt($(this).val());
  $("#peosone option").each((index, item) => {
    if (parseInt($(item).val()) > currValue) $(item).attr("disabled", "disabled");
  });
  var oneValue = parseInt($("#peosone").val());
  $("#peostwo option").each((index, item) => {
    if (parseInt($(item).val()) > currValue) $(item).attr("disabled", "disabled");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="peos" id="peos" class="peos form-control">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8+</option>
</select>

<select name="peosone" id="peosone" class="peosone form-control">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8+</option>
</select>

<select name="peostwo" id="peostwo" class="peostwo form-control">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8+</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Fixed @mplungjan

Comment: It does not reset if I change the first dropdown

Comment: @JackBashford If i choose value from low to high it is working fine but from high to low it is not working properly